How to make a function accessible from both the object and the class itself?
I have a simple class called Storage that has many methods and properties.
For this question, I'm only interested in making uniques a classmethod and a property in the same time. I don't know if this is possible. I wonder if there is a dynamic processing : based on if uniques is being called from the class or an object, then we should always have the same result for the same input used (here it's data).
class Storage:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @classmethod
    def uniques(cls, data=None):
        if data is None:
            data = cls.data
        return [list(set(item)) for item in data]

Unfortunately, when I try doing both calls one is working but the second one gives error :
data = [["apple", "banana", "apple"], ["cat", "dog", "dog"], ["red", "blue", "red"]]

print(Storage.uniques(data))
# [["banana", "apple"], ["cat", "dog"], ["blue", "red"]]

########################################

print(Storage(data).uniques())

      5 @classmethod
      6 def uniques(cls, data=None):
      7     if data is None:
----> 8         data = cls.data
      9     return [list(set(item)) for item in data]

AttributeError: type object 'Storage' has no attribute 'data'

Can you guys show me how to deal with that ? Is this even possible ?

I just wanted to try it. I think this is what you are looking for.
class Storage:
    def __init__(self, data):
         self.data = data

    def uniques(instance_or_data):
        if isinstance(instance_or_data, Storage):
            data = instance_or_data.data
        else:
            data = instance_or_data
        print(data)


Storage.uniques('X')
X

Storage('X').uniques()
X

Storage('Y').uniques()
Y

Storage.uniques('Y')
Y


I replaced print(data) with return [list(set(item)) for item in data] and then I got what I expect. Your solution and the ones of @MichaelButscher and vassiliev all work but I find yours easy to understand. Thanks my friend.

The following works but is ugly and I wouldn't recommend to use it:
class Storage:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        
        self.uniques = lambda: self.__class__.uniques(data)


    @classmethod
    def uniques(cls, data):
        return [list(set(item)) for item in data]
      
    
# Testing

data = [["apple", "banana", "apple"], ["cat", "dog", "dog"], ["red", "blue", "red"]]

print(Storage.uniques(data))

print(Storage(data).uniques())

It creates for each instance a new method (using lambda) bound to this instance only. The attribute lookup mechanism will find this method first if it is applied to the instance.

Thank you my friend. Your solution works but with the fact that my actual function has more than 50 lines, it means that I need 100 lines and if I needed to change how the function works, then I need to do it twice. I wonder if there is a way to define the function only once.

@VERBOSE I updated it so there is much less code in the constructor and no repetition.

Note that this flouts type safety, if you care about that sort of thing

Please try this:
class Storage:
     data = []
     def __init__(self, data):
         setattr(Storage, 'data', data)
 
     @classmethod
     def uniques(cls, data=None):
         if data is None:
             data = cls.data
         return [list(set(item)) for item in data]
     


data = [["apple", "banana", "apple"], ["cat", "dog", "dog"], ["red", "blue", "red"]]
print(Storage.uniques(data))
print(Storage(data).uniques())

